# If a spell gives an enhancement bonus to an attribute, does that affect the base attribute or the modifier?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

For example, Cat's Grace gives a +4 bonus to Dexterity. Would that translate to a +4 for all dexterity checks or a +4 to the base attribute and therefore only a +2 to the skill checks?

Comment: Good question: I've had a lot of my own players need this explaining, so having an answer on here is handy.

Answer (score 13):

The spell Cat's Grace gives a +4 Enhancement bonus to your Dexterity Attribute. This would increase your Dexterity modifier ( And dexterity related skill checks ) by +2.

Also keep in mind when starting to get into the stacking of ability bonuses that you do not try to stack multiple types of Enhancement bonuses together. The Enhancement bonus from Gloves of Dexterity does not stack with Cat's Grace. However, the Enhancement bonus from Cat's grace would still stack with the +2 Morale bonus to dexterity from Elation.

A good rule of thumb is that only Dodge Bonuses and Circumstance bonuses stack with themselves. Everything else does not stack. So if you have a +2 to Natural armor as your current race choice equipping an Amulet of Natural Armor +1 will not increase your Armor Class.

Don't forget that Cat's grace will also increase your Reflex save, Initiative, and possibly your Armor class by +2 as well. ( Depending on your Max Dex with your armor )

Comment: +1 for stacking and side effects. It also affects your initiative, your tasty, tasty initiative.

Comment: +1'd for reminding me about initiative! I've changed the post to compensate.

Comment: If your race has 2 Natural armor then equipping an Amulet of Natural Armor +1 will indeed increase your AC because it is an Enhancement bonus to the Natural Armor bonus. " This amulet, usually crafted from bone or beast scales, toughens the wearer’s body and flesh, giving him an enhancement bonus to his natural armor bonus of from +1 to +5, depending on the kind of amulet. "

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the +1 to +5 depends on the type of amulet, the minimum being from +1 and the maximum being +5. The handbook clearly states that only Dodge and Circumstance bonuses stack, Bonuses from natural armor no matter the source do not stack with each other, unless you have some wizards errata that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Sandwich Simanos is correct about the end result: a character with +2 natural armor from race and a +1 amulet (and no other natural-armor-related stuff) would find his AC 3 points, not 2, higher than if he had neither of those. You are mostly correct that only Dodge and Circumstance bonuses stack with others of the same type (it's actually Dodge, *most* Circumstance, and bonuses with explicit stacking), but in this case, it's not the two stacking together, it's the one modifying the other. The amulet is enhance to natural. Its +1 causes the +2 natural to AC from race to become a +3 bonus.

Answer (score 9):

+4 to the base attribute, thus +2 to skill checks.  "The spell grants a +4 enhancement bonus to Dexterity," not to the bonus.